# Match "war" but not "software"

Tags: regex, grep

What regular expression would match an occurrence of the string "war" that doesn't have the string "soft" in front of it?  In other words the "war" in "world war iii" would match, but the "war" in "where's my software" would not?  Further, "stay out of my warehouse" would match, so would "aware".  In other words, I just don't want the string "software" to match.

Comment: You're looking for a negative lookahead.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: You need to tell us which regex engine you're expecting the answer to work in.

Comment: I would use egrep for this particular query.  But if that would not do the trick I would use Java.

Comment: OMG this is the fastest responding tag on SO I've yet encountered!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your regex engine supports lookbehinds: `(?<!soft)war`.

You can try it using Perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /(?<!soft)war/i' < my-text-file
```

That will work more or less like `grep` (but `grep` does not support lookbehinds, afaik).

Comment: That works.  Would I be too needy if I asked for a case insensitive version?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the example (it's just an i after the last slash).

Answer (score 1):

try this: '[^soft].*war' , its close but not perfect, put in your string combinations and you will see why, also it does not return anything if its only 'war' it doesnt identify, it requires to precede the word with atleast one letter, but it cant precede with 'soft' Can you use conditions in your program and combine this logic with a regex matching for the word war which is not a part of any subsstring as melwil pointed out?